# Finding generators of a group from its action on a topological space

Tags: proof-verification, group-actions, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, finitely-generated

*Summary*

I believe I've written a geometric group theory flavoured proof with a mistake in it, but I'm struggling to see why it might be wrong. I haven't found a counter example, but it also feels too good to be true. Can someone please verify my proof?

---

*Background*

I'm currently trying to understand generators of groups from group actions on topological spaces. The case of importance is group actions on simplicial complexes, and I've proven the desired result in a very convincing manner. Namely, I showed that if $D$ is a subcomplex of a connected simplicial complex $C$, $G$ acts by simplicial automorphisms, and $GD = C$, then $S = \{g\in G: gD\cap D \neq \varnothing\}$ generates $G$. The fact that $C$ is a simplicial complex was crucial in my proof.

However, when I attempted to generalise the result, I ended up obtaining a much more general result with a much simpler proof. For this reason I suspect there is a mistake in my proof. Can someone please correct me if I've made an assumption somewhere?

---

*Statement and Proof*

Claim: 
Let $X$ be a connected topological space, and $G$ a group acting on $X$. Suppose $D$ is an open subset of $X$ such that $GD = X$. Then $S = \{g\in G: gD\cap D \neq \varnothing\}$ generates $G$.

Proof: Let $A = \langle S\rangle$. We first show that $(G\setminus A)D$ is disjoint from $AD$. Let $g \in G$, and suppose that $gD \cap AD \neq \varnothing$. Then there exists $a \in A$ such that $gD \cap aD \neq \varnothing$, so $a^{-1}g D \cap D \neq \varnothing$. By definition, this means $a^{-1}g \in S$, so in particular $g \in aS \subset A$. Since this shows that $g$ must have been in $A$ to begin with, $(G\setminus A)D$ is disjoint from $AD$.

But recall that $D$ was open. A group action is a map $G \to \text{Aut}(X)$, so $gD$ is open for every $g \in G$. $AD$ and $(G\setminus A)D$ are then unions of open sets, and are themselves open. Moreover, $AD \cup (G\setminus A)D = X$. Since $X$ is connected, this forces either $AD$ or $(G\setminus A)D$ to be empty. The former is clearly nonempty, so $(G\setminus A)D = \varnothing$. This forces $G = A$ as required.

---

I believe I've seen a similar result in the past and I also felt that it had additional properties, but I can't say for sure. Thank you!

Comment: How is it more general ? A subcomplex isn't open in general. Other than that your proof seems fine.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. My initial thoughts were that I could always forget the simplicial-complex structure and just think of it as a topological space. Then I can replace the subcomplex with an open superset of it. However, it's not a "generalisation" unless I can replace the subcomplex with an open subset (which I can't do in general). Thanks.